Where in the New Testament is God described as a Yahweh?
God is described as Yahweh passim in the Old Testament, but where in the New Testament is God described as a Yahweh?

Am I correct in thinking that passim is Latin for “scattered” or “spread throughout,” and it is used synonymously with “here and there.”  Your one sentence question is not easily understood by persons like myself who speak only English.

There is insufficient detail in the question but @Lesley has provided the missing content in their answer.

Some of the other answers dealt with the translation of words, where Hebrew and Greek use different words for God because they are different languages.
There is also a translation of ideas and their application to persons. Consider the NIV translation of God's words to Moses:

God said to Moses, “I am who I am. This is what you are to say to the
Israelites: ‘I am has sent me to you.’” - Exodus 3:14

Here God is referring to Himself as "I am". In the New Testament, the most relevant way that God is referred to as "I am" is through the revelation of Jesus via his "I am" statements. (From https://www.esv.org/resources/esv-global-study-bible/chart-43-08/)
These are the Metaphorical statements:

I am the bread of life: John 6:35, 48, 51
I am the light of the world: John 8:12; 9:5
I am the door of the sheep: John 10:7, 9
I am the good shepherd: John 10:11, 14
I am the resurrection and the life: John 11:25
I am the way, the truth, and the life: John 14:6
I am the true vine: John 15:1

Then there are the absolute statements:
John 6:20; 8:24, 28, 58; 18:5
For example:

I told you that you would die in your sins; if you do not believe that
I am he, you will indeed die in your sins. - John 8:24

and:

So Jesus said, “When you have lifted up the Son of Man, then you
will know that I am he and that I do nothing on my own but speak just
what the Father has taught me. - John 8:28

and also:

“Very truly I tell you,” Jesus answered, “before Abraham was born, I
am!” - John 8:58

Verse 59 tells us that the crowd understood what Jesus was saying. He was claiming equality or identity with God:

At this, they picked up stones to stone him, but Jesus hid himself,
slipping away from the temple grounds. - John 8:59

So if you really want to see Yahweh in the New Testament, you will find it in the startling statements that Jesus made about himself. By claiming to be the "I am", he was pulling the meaning of the Old Testament name for God into his words and applying that phrase to himself.

The Old Testament (written in Hebrew) is very clear that there is only one Lord God Almighty, creator and sustainer of all life.  In Hebrew, his name is comprised of four consonants – YHWH – without any vowels.  It is known as the Tetragrammaton. This article gives a full explanation.

When reading Scripture aloud, the Jews substituted the tetragrammaton YHWH with the word Adonai (“Lord”). Even in the Septuagint (the Greek translation of the Old Testament), the translators substituted Kurios (“Lord”) for the Divine Name. Eventually, the vowels from Adonai (“Lord”) or Elohim (“God”) found their way in between the consonants of YHWH, thus forming YaHWeH. But this interpolation of vowels does not mean that was how God’s name was originally pronounced. In fact, we aren’t entirely sure if YHWH should have two syllables or three.

Strictly speaking, YHWH is the only proper name for God. It is translated in English Bibles as “LORD” (all capitals) to distinguish it from Adonai, “Lord.” The revelation of the name is given to Moses “I Am who I Am” (Exodus 3:14). This name specifies an immediacy, a presence. Yahweh is present, accessible, near to those who call on Him for deliverance (Psalm 107:13), forgiveness (Psalm 25:11) and guidance (Psalm 31:3).
ADONAI, “Lord”, is used in place of YHWH, which was thought by the Jews to be too sacred to be uttered by sinful men. In the Old Testament, YHWH is more often used in God’s dealings with His people, while Adonai is used more when He deals with the Gentiles.
The Lord God Almighty has many other names and titles, listed here
For example, YAHWEH-TSIDKENU, which means “The Lord our Righteousness”.  As with YHWH-M’Kaddesh, it is God alone who provides righteousness (from the Hebrew word tsidkenu) to man, ultimately in the person of His Son, Jesus Christ, who became sin for us “that we might become the Righteousness of God in Him” (2 Corinthians 5:21).
Another name for the Lord God Almighty is EL-GIBHOR, meaning “Mighty God” (Isaiah 9:6).  This is the name describing the Messiah, Christ Jesus, in this prophetic portion of Isaiah. As a powerful and mighty warrior, the Messiah, the Mighty God, will accomplish the destruction of God’s enemies and rule with a rod of iron (Revelation 19:15).
If I understand your question correctly, there is only one YHWH – the Lord God Almighty, creator and sustainer of all life.  In the New Testament, written in Greek, there is still only one Lord God Almighty and he is identified as ADONAI. However, his only begotten Son, who came to earth to dwell among us as the man named Jesus, also shares many of the titles ascribed to YHWH – his heavenly father.
More information in this article

Thanks you for your efforts here. However, to my faith, this answer sounds very materialistic and is not related to Christian salvation. Psalm 107 appears to be about worldly earthly deliverance rather than about the Perfect Christian Law that sets people free. Psalm 107 says he redeemed from the hand of the foe; He led them by a straight way  to a city where they could settle; He turned the desert into pools of water; they sowed fields and planted vineyards that yielded a fruitful harvest; he blessed them, and their numbers greatly increased, and he did not let their herds diminish. etc

@Dhammadhatu - The deliverance (Psalm 107:13), forgiveness (Psalm 25:11) and guidance (Psalm 31:3) that God gives to His people is not materialistic, although material blessing can and do flow from Yahweh. There is a deep spiritual application here, one that results in salvation for all who turn to God in repentance for their sins and place their faith and trust in Him.

@Dhammadhatu All of the earthly blessings pronounced upon Israel are fulfilled and realised in spiritual blessings descending from the risen and ascended Christ. It is unbelief (not faith) which does not perceive this.

Biblically, according to religion, Israel ceased to exist in 720BC. If you are referring to the "Israel" created by the United Nations in 1947 (including the British occupation & militarization of Zionists starting in 1919), this is New Judea rather than Israel. "Israel" is an ideal from the Old Testament narrative where the people lived according to the Torah. This does not apply to the New Judea created in 1947. The people of New Judea often do not live according to the Torah. Your comment sounds like Modern Politics rather than Christianity.

"Yahweh" is a Hebrew word. The New Testament is written in Greek, so obviously the name "Yahweh" is not used, instead are used Greek titles like "Theos" (God) or "Kurios" (Lord). However the New Testament often quotes texts from the Old Testament, including many texts that refer to Yahweh. For example:
John 1:23 - John, speaking about Jesus, calls himself "the voice of one crying in the wilderness: make straight the way of the Lord". The text he's referencing in Isaiah reads "prepare the way of the Lord (Yahweh)".
Mark 12:29 - Jesus says "The first of all the commandments is, Hear, O Israel; The Lord our God is one Lord: And thou shalt love the Lord thy God with all thy heart, and with all thy soul, and with all thy mind, and with all thy strength: this is the first commandment." This is, of course, a quote from Deuteronomy 6, and "Lord" in the Hebrew text is "Yahweh".
There are a number of other texts I could cite, but I hope these prove the point that the NT authors, even if they didn't use the name "Yahweh", firmly believed in the God who is the Yahweh of the Old Testament.

Thank you for the attempted answer however it is not proof.  John 1:23 is the words of John The Baptist. John was questioned about his actions in John 1:23 & ultimately executed; similar to Jesus.  As for Mark 12:29, the context is Jesus replying to one of the teachers of the law. The whole of Mark 12 is about the chief priests, the teachers of the law & the elders looked for a way to trap & arrest Jesus. Jesus answered the question about the Jewish law, similar to if Jesus was asked a question about Roman law. Jesus ends the exchange referring to the Kingdom (Basileias) of Theou (not Kyrion).

To add Yahweh in the Old Testament is certainly Kyrion (Lord) because Yahweh commands the moral law/Torah. The word "Lord" is common in many religions. Due to the difficulty of Jews understanding Jesus, Paul had to engage in extended arguments about how the Torah in itself does not set people free; does not give grace. Thus Mark 12:29 concludes with Mark 12:34, where Jesus says to the Pharisee “You are not far from the kingdom of God.” In other words, the Pharisee had not yet reached the Kingdom of God that Jesus was revealing. Obviously the Theou of Jesus was not the Kyrion of the Torah.

In other words, when the statement of "And thou shalt love the Lord thy God with all thy heart, and with all thy soul, and with all thy mind, and with all thy strength" is expressed in Deuteronomy 6 in the Old Testament; this statement is in direct reference to the Torah because the Ten Commandments of the Torah are revealed in Deuteronomy 5. This is not the essence of Christianity. This does not sound like The Father who not only forgives sin but is also the Gardener/Pruner of the Vine in John 15. Your Torah answer remains unconvincing to me & certainly not a refuge of faith for me. –

@Dhammadhatu I think the rebuttal is weak. Jesus in Mark 12 uses not just "Kurios" but also "Theos". In other words He clearly associates Yahweh with both Kurios and Theos. You can't just reject the text because you don't like the conclusion. And these are just two examples, there are others I can find if necessary. Also, one of the other answers is correct that, despite the language difference, Revelation 19 uses the shortened form, explicitly identifying God as Yahweh.

Maybe you can find a possible answer in the Appendix of the New World Translation, whose translation committee decided to use the name of God (Yahweh or in common English: Jehovah) in their translation of the Christian Greek scriptures. Here are a few biblical points they make in their explanation for this uncommon practice among Bible translators (among other extra-biblical ones):


The Christian Greek Scriptures themselves report that Jesus often
referred to God’s name and made it known to others. (John 17:6, 11,
12, 26) Jesus plainly stated: “I have come in the name of my Father.”
He also stressed that his works were done in his “Father’s name.”—John
5:43; 10:25.


As an additional note: the Christian faith and logical thinking implies that Jesus must have used God's name. Jesus was a Jew, and being perfect, there was no reason for Jesus not to use God's name, as He could not have used it in vain, nor mispronounced it. Jesus referred many many times to God's name - his wish was to glorify it. (John 12:28)


Since the Christian Greek Scriptures were an inspired addition to the
sacred Hebrew Scriptures, the sudden disappearance of Jehovah’s name
from the text would seem inconsistent. About the middle of the first
century C.E., the disciple James said to the elders in Jerusalem:
“Symeon has related thoroughly how God for the first time turned his
attention to the nations to take out of them a people for his name.”
(Acts 15:14) It would not be logical for James to make such a
statement if no one in the first century knew or used God’s name.

The divine name appears in its abbreviated form in the Christian Greek
Scriptures. At Revelation 19:1, 3, 4, 6, the divine name is embedded
in the word “Hallelujah.” This comes from a Hebrew expression that
literally means “Praise Jah.” “Jah” is a contraction of the name
Jehovah. Many names used in the Christian Greek Scriptures were
derived from the divine name. In fact, reference works explain that
Jesus’ own name means “Jehovah Is Salvation.”



You can read the full appendix here: The Divine Name in the Christian Greek Scriptures
